# TypeError: UrlFetchApp.fetch(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make an API call from this website to my google sheet but getting this error. Can someone guide me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

```
function myFunction() {

var myHeaders = {
     "Accept":"application/JSON, text/javascript, */*;q=0.01"
}; 

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://vixcentral.com/ajax_historical?n1=2023-10-17", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  
}
```

Comment: That likely means `UrlFetchApp` isn't what you think it is. Double check the object and how you're importing it. You may have `UrlFetchApp` as the module instead of an object within the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/JSON, text/javascript, */*;q=0.01"
  };
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://vixcentral.com/ajax_historical?n1=2023-10-17", requestOptions);
  var res = response.getContentText();
  if (response.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    console.error(res);
  }
  console.log(res);
}
```

- By this modification, the response value is shown in the log. And, when an error occurs, the error message is shown as the error in the log.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Thanks that solved the error. But the data is not captured instead shows "hello historical"

Comment: @Joe Abraham About `Thanks that solved the error.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Joe Abraham About your new issue of `But the data is not captured instead shows "hello historical"`, when I request to `http://vixcentral.com/ajax_historical?n1=2023-10-17`, `hello historical` is returned. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. But, if you want to resolve your new issue, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question? By this, it will help users think of a solution. Because your new question is different from your question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?